# Renaming logs and reports in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I know that it's not possible to add or remove sections in a Report for Robot Framework, but I wonder if it's possible to change the name of the Report from the Command Line.

So the reason for this is I have two Projects and they have the following folder structure

- Project A

  - Testsuites
  - Keywords
  - Variables

And I have the exact same Structure for Project B. Project A and Project B are in the same directory.

When I run multiple tests the Log/Report that appears becomes "Testsuites" Test Log, since that's the name of the Folder where it is.

I want to be able to change the name on the command line so on the log it becomes "Project A Test Log" or "Project B" Test log. Would it be something like this?

```
pybot ./testsuites AS Project A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pybot has a `--name` option. From the user guide:

> -N, --name 
>       Sets the name of the top-level test suite.

For slightly more information see http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-the-name

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

You can give names of output files as pybot parameters:

```
pybot ./testsuites -o A.xml -l A.log -r A.html -x A.xunit.xml
```

It might be more convinient to save all files in their own directories:

```
pybot ./testsuites -d A_files
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could mark tests from different projects with different tags and than you could run different tests

```
pybot -i projectA -l projectA_log.html -r projectA_report.html ./testssuites
```

or

```
pybot -i projectA -d projectA ./testssuites
```

Comment: the -l and -r examples you provided worked perfectly for me.